# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float' with NumPy 1.20

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, floating-point, attributeerror

I am trying to get a column using following command from an Excel file

```
i = pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx', sheet_name='sheet1')['column1']
```

In the past code was working well but today it suddenly stopped working with error.

I tried using different version of Pandas and NumPy but this did not work and gave the following error:

> AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'. `np.float` was a deprecated alias for the builtin `float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use `float` by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use `np.float64` here. The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at:
> https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations

Does anyone know how to fix this instead of painfully trying different versions of Pandas and/or numpy?

In past code was working well but now it is not working at all.

Comment: I'm able to access `numpy.float` with NumPy 1.23.5. It produces a warning but works fine otherwise.

Comment: Try: `pip install "numpy<1.24.0" "pandas==1.5.3"`. Don't forget to restart your kernel if you use a notebook.

Comment: What is trying to use `np.float`?  Your own code, or something you import?  You seem to think it is `pandas`.  Does the error traceback actually tell you that, or are you just guessing.  The latest pandas version should have corrected this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of downgrading pandas or numpy like suggested in other answers, try updating the package `openpyxl` to a version >= 3.0.6. This is the [version](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes.html#id47) which fixed that bug.

`openpyxl` is the package which is responsible for reading excel sheets into pandas.

Comment: could you show a traceback that identifies this module as the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I simply uninstalled anaconda then re-installed. It solved the issue. Spent so many hours trying to debug but uninstallation and reinstallation of Anaconda fixed the issue for me. Not the ideal way to fix issue but need to move on ...

Thank for the responses, Friends.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to this link

https://numpy.org/doc/1.20/reference/arrays.scalars.html#other-aliases

Try using `np.float_`, otherwise there are lot of other options on the reference from which you can select the one that satisfies your need.

You can use this by directly mentioning the `dtype` to be used for the column in a dictionary:

```
pd.read_excel(the_file, dtype = {"col1":np.float_})
```